# Merge duplicate items Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, merge, duplicates

I have an array like:

```
{"education": ["place": "Washington", "education": "Bachelor", "Level": "2", ]},
{"education": ["place": "Washington", "education": "Master", "Level": "4", ]},
{"education": ["place": "New York", "education": "Bachelor", "Level": "3", ]},
{"education": ["place": "Atlanta", "education": "Bachelor", "Level": "1", ]},
{"education": ["place": "New York", "education": "Master", "Level": "4", ]}
```

I want loop over these array and group by place and get something like this:

```
{"education": ["place": "Washington", {"education": "Bachelor", "Level": "2"}, {"education": "Master", "Level": "4" }],
{"education": ["place": "New York", "education": "Bachelor", "Level": "3", ]},
{"education": ["place": "Atlanta", "education": "Bachelor", "Level": "1", ]},
{"education": ["place": "New York", "education": "Master", "Level": "4", ]}
```

Comment: That looks like a dictionary

Comment: Could you provide me more information about dictionary?

Comment: Your data structure looks like a dictionary. Also known as a `Map` in java. Can you show the Java code you tried

Comment: @FerhatKarahanli Why dont try something on your own first. Then post the problems you face.

Comment: @FerhatKarahanli, what is the type of the items that you're manipulating? By the format shown it looks like JSON, is it?

Comment: Sounds like a `Map` of `List`s. e.g. `educationMap = new HashMap<List<Education>>`